# Error message: createProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, php, android, android-studio, mobile-development

I have tried to import uvc camera project into android studio  and after I sync the gradle I try to run the application .But then I get an error and I couldn't solve it.

The Error -:

> Task :opencv:ndkBuild FAILED
> Execution failed for task ':opencv:ndkBuild'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'null/ndk-build.cmd''

I also attached a screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed this by setting sdk and ndk in local.properties

For me it was adding those lines at the end of the file :

sdk.dir=C:\Users\luou\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (It was already there)
ndk.dir=C:\Users\luou\Downloads\android-ndk-r13b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r13b